# Task.assignee is always null [asana]

Tags: asana

I'm using AsanaNet - which works great, but task assignee is always null, even though the Asana console shows these tasks as having an assignee.

```
var asana = new Asana("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz", AuthenticationType.Basic, errorCallback);
            asana.GetWorkspaces(o =>
            {
                foreach (AsanaWorkspace sp in o)
                {
                    asana.GetUsersInWorkspace(sp, u =>
                        {
                            foreach (AsanaUser user in u)
                            {
                                //Get a List of WORKSPACES
                                asana.GetTasksInWorkspace(sp, user, t =>
                                    {
                                        foreach (AsanaTask task in t)
                                        {
                                            asana.GetProjectsOnATask(task, p =>
                                                {
                                        foreach (AsanaProject project in p)
                                        {
                                            bool bSuccess = ProcessTask(task, project);
                                        }
                                                }).Wait();
                                        }
                                    }).Wait();
                            }
                        }).Wait();
                }
            }).Wait();
```

Comment: The solution was to add this to the query string:

tasks?opt_fields=name,id,assignee,notes&assignee=.....

Now the Assignee shows up as the user ID number

Comment: That's odd, the default fields returned if you do not specify `opt_fields` should include assignee by default.